# Extracting multiple strings and combining to .csv in bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a long list of ID's I need to parse. I want to extract three pieces of information and write to a 3 column CSV. Column 1 = the field between tr|XXXX|, column 3 = the field after the second | but before OS=.

Column 2 would be conditional. If there is 'GN=XXX' in the line, I'd like it to return XXX. If GN= isn't present, I'd like to write the first section of column 3 (i.e. up to the first space).

Input:

```
>tr|I1WXP1|I1WXP1_9EURY Methyl coenzyme M reductase subunit A (Fragment) OS=uncultured euryarchaeote OX=114243 GN=mcrA PE=4 SV=1
>tr|A0A059VAR9|A0A059VAR9_9EURY V-type ATP synthase beta chain (Fragment) OS=Halorubrum sp. Ga66 OX=1480727 GN=atpB PE=3 SV=1
>tr|Q51760|Q51760_9EURY Glutaredoxin-like protein OS=Pyrococcus furiosus OX=2261 PE=1 SV=1
```

Desired output:

```
I1WXP1,mcrA,I1WXP1_9EURY Methyl coenzyme M reductase subunit A (Fragment)
A0A059VAR9,atpB, A0A059VAR9_9EURY V-type ATP synthase beta chain (Fragment)
Q51760,Q51760_9EURY,Q51760_9EURY Glutaredoxin-like protein
```

I can get the first two with awk, for e.g.:

```
awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[2]
```

But I can't work out the conditional, or how to act on the 'GN=' pattern neatly.

So for example, extracting bold text:

```
tr|**I1WXP1**|**I1WXP1_9EURY Methyl coenzyme M reductase subunit A (Fragment)** OS=uncultured euryarchaeote OX=114243 GN=**mcrA** PE=4 SV=1
```

Becomes:

```
I1WXP1, mcrA, I1WXP1_9EURY Methyl coenzyme M reductase subunit A(Fragment)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever your input contains tag=value pairs as yours does I find it best to first create an array to contain that mapping and then you can access the values by their tags (names) however you like, e.g. using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[|]"; OFS="," }
{
    delete tag2val

    description = $3; sub(/ +[^ ]+=.*/,"",description)
    assignments = substr($3,length(description)+1)

    tag2val["GN"] = description; sub(/ .*/,"",tag2val["GN"])

    split(assignments,a," ")
    for ( i in a ) {
        tag = a[i]; sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
        val = substr(a[i],length(tag)+2)
        tag2val[tag] = val
    }

    print $2, tag2val["GN"], description
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
I1WXP1,mcrA,I1WXP1_9EURY Methyl coenzyme M reductase subunit A (Fragment)
A0A059VAR9,atpB,A0A059VAR9_9EURY V-type ATP synthase beta chain (Fragment)
Q51760,Q51760_9EURY,Q51760_9EURY Glutaredoxin-like protein
```

With that approach if you want to print or test other fields it's trivial, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[|]"; OFS="," }
{
    delete tag2val

    description = $3; sub(/ +[^ ]+=.*/,"",description)
    assignments = substr($3,length(description)+1)

    tag2val["GN"] = description; sub(/ .*/,"",tag2val["GN"])

    split(assignments,a," ")
    for ( i in a ) {
        tag = a[i]; sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
        val = substr(a[i],length(tag)+2)
        tag2val[tag] = val
    }

    print $2, tag2val["GN"], tag2val["OS"], tag2val["PE"], description
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
I1WXP1,mcrA,uncultured,4,I1WXP1_9EURY Methyl coenzyme M reductase subunit A (Fragment)
A0A059VAR9,atpB,Halorubrum,3,A0A059VAR9_9EURY V-type ATP synthase beta chain (Fragment)
Q51760,Q51760_9EURY,Pyrococcus,1,Q51760_9EURY Glutaredoxin-like protein
```

Answer (score 0):

***1st solution(GNU `awk` version):*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -F'^>tr\\|| OS=' '
BEGIN{ OFS="," }
NF>=2{
  gsub(/\|/,OFS,$2)
  match($0,/GN=(\S+)/,gnArray)
  if(gnArray[1]==""){
    match($2,/(^[^,]*),(\S+)(.*)/,NoGNfoundArr)
    val=NoGNfoundArr[1] OFS NoGNfoundArr[2] OFS NoGNfoundArr[2]  NoGNfoundArr[3]
  }
  else{
    match($2,/(^[^,]*),(.*)/,GNFoundArr)
    val=GNFoundArr[1] OFS gnArray[1] OFS GNFoundArr[2]
  }
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution(with any `awk` version):*** Adding additional `awk` code which should work with any version of it.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ OFS="," }
match($0,/^>tr.* OS=/){
  val1=substr($0,RSTART+4,RLENGTH-8)
  gsub(/\|/,",",val1)
  match($0,/GN=[^[:space:]]+/)
  val2=substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3)
  if(val2){
    match(val1,/^[^,]*/)
    print substr(val1,RSTART,RLENGTH),val2 substr(val1,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  else{
    match(val1,/,[^[:space:]]+/)
    print substr(val1,1,RSTART-1),substr(val1,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1),substr(val1,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1) substr(val1,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative in `sed`:

```
sed -e '/.*tr|\([^|]*\)|\(.*\) OS=.* GN=\([^ ]*\).*/{s//\1,\3,\2/;b;}' \
    -e 's/.*tr|\([^|]*\)|\(\([^ ]*\).*\) OS=.*/\1,\3,\2/'              \
file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 's/^[^|]*\|([^|]*)\|(.*) OS.*GN=(\S+).*/\1,\3,\2/p;t
         s/^[^|]*\|([^|]*)\|((\S+).*) OS.*/\1,\3,\2/p' file
```

Use pattern matching and back references to format the desired result.

If the first match fails use the second.

If neither matches no output.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Awk

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=","}
    /GN=/ { gn=gensub(/.* GN=([^ ]*) .*/,"\\1",1) }
    !/GN=/ { gn=gensub(/ .*/,"",1,$3) }
    { sub(/ OS=.*$/,""); print $2,gn,$3 }
' file

I1WXP1,mcrA,I1WXP1_9EURY Methyl coenzyme M reductase subunit A (Fragment)
A0A059VAR9,atpB,A0A059VAR9_9EURY V-type ATP synthase beta chain (Fragment)
Q51760,Q51760_9EURY,Q51760_9EURY Glutaredoxin-like protein
```

---

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=","}
    match($3,/(.*) OS=.* GN=([^ ]*) .*/,a) {
        print $2,a[2],a[1] 
        next
    }
    match($3,/^([^ ]*) (.*) OS=.*/,a){
        print $2,a[1],a[1]" "a[2]
    }
' file

I1WXP1,mcrA,I1WXP1_9EURY Methyl coenzyme M reductase subunit A (Fragment)
A0A059VAR9,atpB,A0A059VAR9_9EURY V-type ATP synthase beta chain (Fragment)
Q51760,Q51760_9EURY,Q51760_9EURY Glutaredoxin-like protein
```